# How to reuse a ui-router state in different states?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a ui-router state that I use to display some info about a movie in an overlay. The data it displays is always the same, and the data it recieves is also always the same. But I'm using that state multiple times in my ui-router controller, but with different state parameters.

I have 4 states from where I call this `trailer` state,

- home.container-big.trailer
- home.suggestions.container-big.trailer
- friendprofile.container-big.trailer
- home.activities.movie-info.trailer

These are the 4 states I call the `trailer` state.

So for each click I have a different state although everything except the state name is different.

So I was thinking this,

I've create a stateProvider

```
$stateProvider
  .state('trailer',{
    params: {
      trailer_link: null
    },
    url: '',
    views: {
      "youtube_trailer":{
        templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_container-trailer.html',
        controller: function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
          $scope.trailer_link = $stateParams.trailer_link;
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

And I want to call it inside the `home.container-big` state like so,

```
%a{"ui-sref" => ".trailer({trailer_link: '{{ trailer.link }}'})"} Trailer {{$index+1}}
```

The click produces this error

> Could not resolve '.trailer' from state 'home.container-big'

Which makes sence. So I'm thinking I need to pass the current state in the click to the name of the ui-state. Is this possible? Or is there another way I can reuse the same state in different states?

Comment: I think a directive fits your needs more than substates.

Comment: Ah yes, that might be a very good idea as well.